# How to read PassportJS session data?

Tags: node.js, express, passport.js

I think that I don't quite understand what `passport.session` is meant for. It says nothing on the [configuration page](http://passportjs.org/guide/configure/).

What I need is to save the person's data once he's been authenticated, then use his name in an another required file, where I put all my Socket.io code. I've read so much on Google and here, and just couldn't find what I need. I don't know how to read the `connect.sess` which has that data once the user is logged-in.

So what does this line do?

`app.use(passport.session());`

Note - I don't use a DB. A user just logs-in so I could get his ID and Name, that's pretty basic.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure if this is always the case, but I recently finished writing a blog that uses Node and Passport, and whenever a user is logged in their credentials are always stored in `req.user` (assuming `req` is what your request JSON is called). So you might want to check there.

Comment: what are you calling your parameters to the functions that are called in your `routes` file?

Comment: yes, I put a console log there now: `req.user` is undefined..why should I have a `user` thing on my `req` object?

Comment: Just checked, it works like this: `req.session.passport.user`

Comment: In the file `/node_modules/passport/lib/passport/middleware/authenticate.js` look at the function `authenticate(name, options, callback)`. If there is a successful authentication, it calls `req.logIn`, which in turn sets `req.user` to the information supplied to Passport.

Comment: Oh, yeah. It also sets `req.session.passport.user` but that appears to only be UserID (at least on my computer, the way I have it set up).